# How to get rid of annoying Photoshop hover info message? It cannot be discarded and appears on all screens

Tags: 14.04, wine, photoshop

I have Photoshop CS 6 on Ubuntu 14.04. When I hover over some tool or button in Photoshop, a description message will appear (showing what this tool is, and so on).

However, it somehow freezes and stays static on all virtual screen. Look at the image. The message appeared on screen 1, and this is what I see on all other screens.

[image]

Another sample

[image]

Can this be solved or I have to find a way to disable this message?

Comment: no one has this issue???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a round solution and disabled the Tooltip via `Preferences > Interface > Show Tool Tips`

Until someone posts a better solution, I shall mark this one as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the tooltips, use this script to launch photoshop - it is a compromise/workaround. The script hides the non-disapearing tooltip whenever the mouse hovers over and leaves it.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

wine /usr/local/apps/photoshop/Photoshop.exe "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
p=$!

# Move the non-disapearing tooltips to right to off screen
xdotool search --sync --all --onlyvisible --pid "$p" --name "^$" \
    behave %@ mouse-leave windowmove %@ 100% y &
px=$!

wait $p
kill $px
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable tooltips in CC 2015 by going into `Edit > Preferences > Tools > Show Tool Tips`